# Como usar round em função lambda

Tags: python, expressões-lambda

Quero entender como posso incluir o round na função a seguir:

```
lstNumerosF = [10.01, 7.03, 2.23]


lstMapa = list(map(lambda x: x ** 2, lstNumerosF))

print(lstMapa)
```

Queria usar dentro da função lambda o round para arredondar os elementos para 3 casas decimais.

Comment: Não é só fazer `lambda x: round(x ** 2, 3)`?

Comment: Isso mesmo!
Muito obrigada! Me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quer chamar `round` dentro do *lambda*, basta fazer isso:

```
lstNumerosF = [10.01, 7.03, 2.23]
lstMapa = list(map(lambda x: round(x ** 2, 3), lstNumerosF))
print(lstMapa) # [100.2, 49.421, 4.973]
```

---

Mas no seu caso talvez nem precise de `map` e *lambda*, basta usar uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lstNumerosF = [10.01, 7.03, 2.23]
lstMapa = [ round(x ** 2, 3) for x in lstNumerosF ]
print(lstMapa) # [100.2, 49.421, 4.973]
```